# VertX and Log4j cannot get configuration

Tags: java, logging, log4j, vert.x

I am working with VertX, I want to use Log4J as logger for my code and for the exthernal libraries.

So I wrote down this piece of code:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Main extends AbstractVerticle {

   final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("Gimli");

   @Override
   public void start(Future<Void> fut) throws Exception {
      System.setProperty("vertx.logger-delegate-factory-class-name", " io.vertx.core.logging.Log4j2LogDelegateFactory"); // Default logger

    logger.debug("Debug log");
    logger.error("Error log");
    logger.warn("Warning log");
  }
}
```

and I put into *src/main/resources* the file *log4j.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Configuration>
  <Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="app_file" append="true" fileName="/var/log/seachlog.log" filePattern="/var/log/vertx/$${date:yyyy-MM}/seachlog-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{ISO8601} %-5p %c:%L - %m%n" />
        <Policies>
            <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="5MB" />
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
    <RollingFile name="vertx_file" append="true" fileName="/var/log/vertx.log" filePattern="/var/log/vertx/$${date:yyyy-MM}/vertx-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{ISO8601} %-5p %c:%L - %m%n" />
        <Policies>
            <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="5MB" />
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
    <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <!-- <LogStashJSONLayout/> -->
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{ISO8601} %-5p %c:%L - sfsdfsdfsdfsdf %m%n" />
    </Console>
</Appenders>

<Loggers>
    <Logger name="Gimli" level="DEBUG">
        <!-- <AppenderRef ref="vertx_rollingFile" /> -->
        <!-- <AppenderRef ref="vertx_socket" /> -->
        <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="vertx_file" />
    </Logger>
    <Root level="DEBUG">
        <!-- <AppenderRef ref="vertx_socket" /> -->
        <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="app_file" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

But the output seems not changing:

```
2017-12-09 09:21:34,503 DEBUG [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] [Gimli] Debug log (Main.java:31)
2017-12-09 09:21:34,505 ERROR [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] [Gimli] Error log (Main.java:32)
2017-12-09 09:21:34,507 WARN  [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] [Gimli] Warning log (Main.java:33)
```

How can I set the configuration file correctly?

Answer (score 6):

First of all it looks like you are combining `log4j` with `log4j2` config file. That could be reason why your config is not loaded.  
But I recommend to use vert.x logging feature - you can use log4j or log4j2 with it too. You will define your loggers as this:

```
import io.vertx.core.logging.Logger;
import io.vertx.core.logging.LoggerFactory;

Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("Gimli");
```

then use this normally as you did. so:

```
logger.debug("Debug log");
logger.error("Error log");
logger.warn("Warning log");
```

next you will keep your config in `src/main/resources`. Just be careful because this is log4j2 config. So it should be named `log4j2.xml`. 
And now you just need to specify logger delegate factory for vertx. For log4j or log4j2 its:

```
io.vertx.core.logging.Log4jLogDelegateFactory
```

or

```
io.vertx.core.logging.Log4j2LogDelegateFactory
```

you can setup system property `vertx.logger-delegate-factory-class-name` or you can specify VM argument as this:

```
-Dvertx.logger-delegate-factory-class-name=io.vertx.core.logging.Log4j2LogDelegateFactory
```

(for log4j2)  
 
More info in [documentation](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_logging)

Comment: I'm having the same problem as the OP.  My console output tells me I'm using log4j2, yet my log4j2.yml isn't being found:
WARN StatusLogger Found configuration file log4j2.yml for inactive ConfigurationFactory org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.yaml.YamlConfigurationFactory
ERROR StatusLogger No Log4j 2 configuration file found. Using default ...But, even with that, I would expect that I could use parameterized log statements.  However, they aren't working:            LOGGER.info( "Chat message received: {}", message.body() );   produces [INFO] INFO: Chat message received: {}

Comment: Found my problem: tracing the code execution shows me I get here: "if (isEnabled(level, marker, message, params)) { logMessage(fqcn, level, marker, message, params); }  in log4j2.  However, the condition on the log level returns false, indicating INFO is not the default.  I find that strange.  However, forcing the logger to execute, I get the correct parameterized output " Chat message received: test".  What I find quite strange is that I get console output that must be using another logging implementation, otherwise I shouldn't have seen my log statement at all.  Is this a bug or feature?

Comment: Using `io.vertx.core.logging.Logger` and `io.vertx.core.logging.LoggerFactory` is now deprecated as the vertx loggers are going to be made internal. This should no longer be recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I resolved, the main problem was in the maven configuration. I added the following lines to my build script

```
 <build>
   <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>/</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>config.json</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
 </build>
```

this way maven would consider `/` the resources folder and not `/src/main/resources` so log4j cannot find the `log4j.properties` file